# Yeoman / GruntJS / UseMin

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I am trying to build my files using usemin. my setup is like this: index.html - /en/bunchofhtmlfiles.html  - /de/bunchofhtmlfiles.html - /scripts/apps.js

index.html

-- /en/ -> html files

-- /scripts/ -> js files

How do i write the build:js blocks?

In index.html its clear:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/... -->
<script src="scripts/...></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But what do i write in the subdirs?

```
<!-- build:js ../scripts/...  -->
<script src="../scripts/...></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Puts the scripts in a directory "before" root.

```
<!-- build:js scripts/...  -->
<script src="scripts/...></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This leaves the files with the wrong paths to the js files but the js files get placed correctly.

Here is the gruntfile.js part for usemin:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/en/*.html'],
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/en/*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to touch the Gruntfile.js

You need to go threw the whole index.html and change the paths inside the uncommented areas.

e.g.

```
root/scripts/main.js
```

and your index.html

```
root/en/index.html
```

you need to change the index.html from

```
  <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Into

```
  <!-- build:js ../scripts/main.js -->
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Same for your other paths